# ansible read local file to var and then loop read line by line

Tags: file, loops, ansible, line-by-line

I would like to create a playbook that reads a local file to a var, Then be able to loop through this var line by line and use the lines in a task.

To get the file content i used:

```
file_contents: "{{lookup('file', './myfile.txt')}}"
```

I tried using:

- with_file
- with_item
- with_lines

But I did not get the result i wanted.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Python built-ins for some types, like strings, for example.

So this will do the trick for you:

```
file_contents_lines: "{{ lookup('file', './aaa.txt').splitlines() }}"
```

and

```
with_items: "{{ file_contents_lines }}"
```